# How to write this snippet more clean

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In a turn-based game, I'd like to find the previous player.
To find the next player, I can just type:

```
int lastPlayer = match.currentPlayer - 1;
```

The problem is when the currentPlayer is player 1. Then lastPlayer becomes 0, which is wrong. It should be player6.

To fix this, I can do:

```
    int lastPlayer = match.currentPlayer - 1;

    if (lastPlayer == 0)
        lastPlayer = match.numberOfPlayers;
```

My question is how to write this in a cleaner way. I know game center, turn based code do something like:

```
    (currentIndex + 1) % match.participants.count];
```

How can I rewrite my code to do the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does the count  start from zero?

Comment: Probably better asking this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about that?

```
int lastPlayer = match.currentPlayer > 1 ? match.currentPlayer - 1 : match.numberOfPlayers;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a turn counter like this:

```
for(int i=0;i< maxTurns;i++){//do something}
```

and player1 plays the 1st turn, player2 the second and so on,
you can get the current players number exactly as its done in gamecenter.

Maybe you don't know the modulo "%" operator,
it returns the rest of a division, for example

```
3%2 = 1
```

your turncounter keeps counting up so the next player is

```
(turncounter + 1)%match.numberOfPlayer
```

in this case the modulo operator kind of "resets" your counter when it reaches the max player count (its round 6 and there are 5 players 6%5 = 1).

To sum it up, currentPlayer is `turncounter%match.numberOfPlayer`

nextPlayer is `++turncounter%match.numberOfPlayer`